# Is there a way to stop fread reading characters into an array in a struct following a whitespace?

Tags: c, fread

I'm attempting to do homework for my second-semester programming class in which we have to read data from a file like this:

```
Fred 23 2.99
Lisa 31 6.99
Sue 27 4.45
Bobby 456  18.844
Ann   7  3.45
```

using structs in fread. I'll eventually have to create a loop to read all of the data then convert it to binary and write it to a file but this is as far as I've gotten before running into a problem:

```
struct data
{
    char name[25];
    int iNum;
    float fNum;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct data mov;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    fread(&mov, sizeof(struct data), 1, fp);
    printf(" name: %s\n int: %d\n float: %f\n", mov.name, mov.iNum, mov.fNum);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that fread will read the first 25 characters into the array instead of stopping at the first whitespace, so it produces output like this:

```
 name: Fred 23 2.99
Lisa 31 6.99
Sue 27 4.4
 int: 926031973
 float: 0.000000
```

instead of the desired result, which would be something more like:

```
 name: Fred
 int: 23
 float: 2.99000
```

From what I've read, I believe this is how fread is supposed to function, and I'm sure there's a better way of going about this problem, but the assignment requires we use fread and a 25 character array in our struct. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: If the assignment requires you to use only `fread` to read from the file, then you are supposed to read into a buffer (an array of `char` you supply) and then examine the buffer to see where spaces and line endings are. Then it is your job to interpret the things in the buffer and use them to assign values to members of the structure.

Comment: There are only three ways to read a file:1)read a character 2) read a line 3) read a buffer/N-characters. . All three are basically *attempts*

Comment: A file with varying length lines is not designed to be read by `fread()` unless you're going to slurp the whole file into memory and then parse the memory.  The data shown should be read by `fgets()` and parsed with `sscanf()` into the structure, and then written from the structure into a binary file.  You can then read the binary file with `fread()` and edit it and rewrite it back again, with fixed size records.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher wants you to use `fread` and not `fscanf`? Even if you are supposed to parse the input and manually convert string to `int`, `fgetc` is better suited to the job than `fread`.  Or are you showing us the wrong input, and the data is supposed to already be binary and not ascii?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to stop fread reading characters into an array in a
>   struct following a whitespace?

*Answer: Yes*  (but not with `fread` directly, you'll need a buffer to accomplish the task)

The requirement you use `fread` to parse formatted-text from an input file is certainly an academic exercise (a good one at that), but not something you would normally do. Why? Normally when you are concerned with reading lines of data from a file, you use a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`.

You could also use the *character-oriented* input function `fgetc()` and simply read from the file, buffering the input, until the `'\n'` is found, do what you need with the buffer and repeat. Your last normal option (but discouraged due to it fragility) is to use a *formatted-input* function like `fscanf()` -- but its misuse accounts for a significant percentage of questions on this site.

But, if for an academic challenge, you must use `fread()`, then as mentioned in the comments you will want to read the entire file into an allocated buffer, and then parse that buffer as if you were reading it a line-at-a-time from the actual file. `sscanf` would be used if reading with `fgets()` and it can be used here to read from the buffer filled with `fread()`. The only trick is keeping track of where you are within the buffer to start each read -- and knowing where to stop.

With that outline, how do you approach reading an entire file into a buffer with `fread()`? You first need to obtain the file length to know how much space to allocate. You do that either by calling `stat` or `fstat` and utilizing the `st_size` member of the filled `struct stat` containing the filesize, or you use `fseek` to move to the end of the file and use `ftell()` to report the offset in bytes from the beginning.

A simple function that takes an open `FILE*` pointer, saves the current position, moves the file-position indicator to the end, obtains the file-size with `ftell()` and then restores the file-position indicator to its original position could be:

```
/* get the file size of file pointed to by fp */
long getfilesize (FILE *fp)
{
    fpos_t currentpos;
    long bytes;

    if (fgetpos (fp, &currentpos) == -1) {  /* save current file position */
        perror ("fgetpos");
        return -1;
    }
    if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {    /* fseek end of file */
        perror ("fseek-SEEK_END");
        return -1;
    }
    if ((bytes = ftell (fp)) == -1) {       /* get number of bytes */
        perror ("ftell-bytes");
        return -1;
    }
    if (fsetpos (fp, &currentpos) == -1) {  /* restore file positon */
        perror ("fseek-SEEK_SET");
        return -1;
    }

    return bytes;   /* return number of bytes in file */
}
```

(**note:** above each step is validated and `-1` is returned on error, otherwise the file-size is returned on success. Make sure you validate each step in your program and always provide a meaningful return from your functions that can indicate success/failure.)

With the file-size in hand, all you need to do before calling `fread()` is to allocate a block of memory large enough to hold the contents of the file and assign the starting address to that block of memory to a pointer that can be used with `fread()`. For example:

```
    long bytes;                     /* size of file in bytes */
    char *filebuf, *p;              /* buffer for file and pointer to it */
    ...
    if ((bytes = getfilesize (fp)) == -1)   /* get file size in bytes */
        return 1;

    if (!(filebuf = malloc (bytes + 1))) {  /* allocate/validate storage */
        perror ("malloc-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
```

(we will talk about the `+ 1` later on)

Now you have adequate storage for your file and the address for the storage is assigned to the pointer `filebuf`, you can call `fread()` and read the entire file into that block of memory with:

```
    /* read entire file into allocated memory */
    if (fread (filebuf, sizeof *filebuf, bytes, fp) != (size_t)bytes) {
        perror ("fread-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now your entire file is stored in the block of memory pointed to by `filebuf`. How do you parse the data line-by-line into your struct (or actually an array of struct so each record is stored within a separate struct)? It's actually pretty easy. You just read from the buffer and keep track of the number of characters used to read up until a `'\n'` is found, parsing the information in that line into a struct element of the array, add the offset to your pointer to prepare for the next read and increment the index on your array of struct to account for the struct you just filled. You are essentially using `sscanf` just as you would if you read the line from the file with `fgets()`, but you are manually keeping track of the offset within the buffer for the next call to `sscanf`, e.g.

```
#define NDATA 16    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC  25

struct data {       /* your struct with fixed array of 25-bytes for name */
    char name[MAXC];
    int iNum;
    float fNum;
};
...
    struct data arr[NDATA] = {{ .name = "" }};  /* array of struct data */
    int used;                       /* no. chars used by sscanf */
    size_t ndx = 0, offset = 0;     /* array index, and pointer offset */
    ...
    filebuf[bytes] = 0; /* trick - nul-terminate buffer for sscanf use */

    p = filebuf;                                /* set pointer to filebuf   */
    while (ndx < NDATA &&                       /* while space in array     */
            sscanf (p + offset, "%24s %d %f%n", /* parse values into struct */
                arr[ndx].name, &arr[ndx].iNum, &arr[ndx].fNum, &used) == 3) {
        offset += used;     /* update offset with used chars */
        ndx++;              /* increment array index */
    }
```

That's pretty much it. You can `free (filebuf);` now that you are done with it and all the values are now stored in your array of struct `arr`.

There is one important line of code above we have not talked about -- and I told you we would get to it later. It is also something you wouldn't normally do, but it mandatory where you are going to process the buffer as text with `sscanf`, a function normally used to process strings. How will you ensure `sscanf` knows were to stop reading and doesn't continue reading beyond the bounds of `filebuf`?

```
    filebuf[bytes] = 0; /* trick - nul-terminate buffer for sscanf use */
```

That's where the `+ 1` on the allocated size comes into play. You don't normally terminate a buffer -- there is no need. However, if you want to process the contents of the buffer with functions normally used to process strings -- then you do. Otherwise, `sscanf` will continue to read past the final `'\n'` in the buffer off into memory you cannot validly access until it finds a random `0` somewhere in the heap. (with the potential of filling additional additional structs with garbage if they happen to satisfy the *format-string*)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NDATA 16    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC  25

struct data {       /* your struct with fixed array of 25-bytes for name */
    char name[MAXC];
    int iNum;
    float fNum;
};

long getfilesize (FILE *fp);    /* function prototype for funciton below */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    struct data arr[NDATA] = {{ .name = "" }};  /* array of struct data */
    int used;                       /* no. chars used by sscanf */
    long bytes;                     /* size of file in bytes */
    char *filebuf, *p;              /* buffer for file and pointer to it */
    size_t ndx = 0, offset = 0;     /* array index, and pointer offset */
    FILE *fp;                       /* file pointer */

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1-arg given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient arguments\n"
                "usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* open file / validate file open for reading */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "rb"))) {
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((bytes = getfilesize (fp)) == -1)   /* get file size in bytes */
        return 1;

    if (!(filebuf = malloc (bytes + 1))) {  /* allocate/validate storage */
        perror ("malloc-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read entire file into allocated memory */
    if (fread (filebuf, sizeof *filebuf, bytes, fp) != (size_t)bytes) {
        perror ("fread-filebuf");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close file, read done */

    filebuf[bytes] = 0; /* trick - nul-terminate buffer for sscanf use */

    p = filebuf;                                /* set pointer to filebuf   */
    while (ndx < NDATA &&                       /* while space in array     */
            sscanf (p + offset, "%24s %d %f%n", /* parse values into struct */
                arr[ndx].name, &arr[ndx].iNum, &arr[ndx].fNum, &used) == 3) {
        offset += used;     /* update offset with used chars */
        ndx++;              /* increment array index */
    }
    free (filebuf);     /* free allocated memory, values stored in array */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)    /* output stored values */
        printf ("%-24s  %4d  %7.3f\n", arr[i].name, arr[i].iNum, arr[i].fNum);

    return 0;
}

/* get the file size of file pointed to by fp */
long getfilesize (FILE *fp)
{
    fpos_t currentpos;
    long bytes;

    if (fgetpos (fp, &currentpos) == -1) {  /* save current file position */
        perror ("fgetpos");
        return -1;
    }
    if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) {    /* fseek end of file */
        perror ("fseek-SEEK_END");
        return -1;
    }
    if ((bytes = ftell (fp)) == -1) {       /* get number of bytes */
        perror ("ftell-bytes");
        return -1;
    }
    if (fsetpos (fp, &currentpos) == -1) {  /* restore file positon */
        perror ("fseek-SEEK_SET");
        return -1;
    }

    return bytes;   /* return number of bytes in file */
}
```

(**note:** approximately 1/2 the lines of code are devoted to ***validating each step***. That is normal and critical to ensure you don't invoke *Undefined Behavior* by blindly continuing forward in your code after a failure occurs that prevents you from processing valid data.)

**Example Use/Output**

With that you program is complete and you should be able to parse the data from the buffer filled by `fread()` having stopped at all appropriate times following a whitespace.

```
$ ./bin/freadinumfnum dat/inumfnum.txt
Fred                        23    2.990
Lisa                        31    6.990
Sue                         27    4.450
Bobby                      456   18.844
Ann                          7    3.450
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/freadinumfnum dat/inumfnum.txt
==5642== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5642== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5642== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5642== Command: ./bin/freadinumfnum dat/inumfnum.txt
==5642==
Fred                        23    2.990
Lisa                        31    6.990
Sue                         27    4.450
Bobby                      456   18.844
Ann                          7    3.450
==5642==
==5642== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5642==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5642==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 623 bytes allocated
==5642==
==5642== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5642==
==5642== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5642== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: As a second-semester exercise, it is more likely the intended approach, assuming the question communicates the problem correctly, is to implement streaming parsing of the file. The student could implement their own routines to get the next string, number, or other expected data from the file, constructing them on a simple buffering scheme using `fread`. Reading the entire file into memory is likely not what was intended, and using `fseek` likely violates the constraint to use only `fread` in regard to the file. It also fails if the input is a terminal or pipe rather than a file on disk.

Comment: Additionally, the answer is not yes, as this answer states, but no.

Comment: You don't see the large parenthetical explaining that point? I.e. `"Answer: Yes (but not with fread directly, you'll need a buffer to accomplish the task):` How do you know what was intended? Are you taking the class? You seem to be wildly speculating to reach some pre-determined conclusion. You have absolutely no basis to support your comment. Let's see your answer.

Comment: Applying the parenthetical expression only yields the nonsensical meaning “Yes, there is a way to stop fread reading characters… following a whitespace but not with fread directly.” In other words, it says both you can stop fread and cannot do it with fread. But the question is: Can you stop fread? The question is not “Can you stop some task that is reading characters following a space?” If it were, then, yes, you can, in general, design a task to stop following a space. But the question is “Can you stop fread…?”, and the answer is “No.” “Yes you can stop fread but not with fread” is nonsense.

Comment: As to knowing what is intended, I have a sense of the progression of computer science curricula, and they are also guided by logic. An exercise intended to use kludgey methods to read an entire file into memory merely for the purpose of simple parsing is ill suited to teaching good software skills. In contrast, assigning students to write some simple parsing of their own instead of using `scanf` is suited to their level of knowledge at a second semester.

Comment: Additionally, it still stands that using `fseek` likely violates the constraint to use only `fread` in regard to the file.

Comment: I could have easily done it incrementally. I could have done it character-by-character, I could have passed to `strtol` and `strtod` - all of that complicates the pointer arithmetic involved for someone who is struggling just to understand the `fread` concept of it. The `25-char` buffer applies specifically to the `.name` member of the struct. There is no limitation on how to approach the problem otherwise. The question mentions reading from a file with `fread` not a pipe. The answer simplifies the solution. Any `"likely"` this or that is rote speculation and not helpful.